# Applying background color based on scrolling content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjvCw/36/)

I want to apply background-color change property to circle when the window slides. Like in the beginning only first circle will have background-color. and when the images slides to second screen the second circle will have only color.

Can anybody guide me how to achieve that.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var A = $('.gallery').scrollLeft();
        if (A < 993) {
            $('.gallery').animate({
                scrollLeft: '+=331px'
            }, 300);
        }
        if (A >= 993) {
            $('.gallery').delay(400).animate({
                scrollLeft: 0
            }, 300);
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution of your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pjvCw/44/ but....

The way you're doing galleries is quite wrong.
You have a really sensitive CSS full of `margin` bugs (see in CSS code),
**you calculate all by hand**, which will just **complicate** your life one day if you'll get to add images, change widths etc...
Your buttons are positioned really wrongly, and again you don't even need to manually add them in your HTML. Let jQuery do all the job for you:

- Calculate margins, widths,
- Get the number of slides
- generate buttons,
- Make your buttons clickable
- Pause gallery on mouseenter (loop again on mouseleave)

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pjvCw/42/)**

This is the way you should go with your slider:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="galleryContainer"> <!-- Note this main 'wrapper' -->

  <div class="gallery">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- ..your images.. -->
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- ..your images.. -->
      </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="content-nav-control"></div>    <!-- Let jQ create the buttons -->

</div>
```

Note the general gallery wrapper, it allows you with this CSS to make your buttons parent not move with the gallery.

**CSS:**

In your code, using `display:inline-block;` adds 4px margin to your elements, ruining your math. So you just need to apply `font-size:0;` to remove that inconvenience.
As soon I did that the math was working and the right width was than 340px, having 5px border for your images and 20px margin.

```
.galleryContainer{ 
  /* you need that one 
  // to prevent the navigation move */
  position:relative; /* cause .content-nav-control is absolute */
  background-color: #abcdef;
  width:340px; /* (instead of 350) now the math will work */
  height: 265px; 
}
.gallery{
   position:relative;
   overflow: hidden; /* "overflow" is enough */
   width:340px; /* (instead of 350) now the math will work */
   height: 265px; 
}

.gallery .row {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size:0; /* prevent inline-block 4px margin issue */
}
.gallery img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.normalimage {
    height: 80px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
.wideimage {
    height: 80px;
    width: 130px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
img:last-of-type {
    margin-right:20px;
}
.content-nav-control {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%; /* cause it's absolute */
  bottom:10px;
  text-align:center; /* cause of inline-block buttons inside*/
  font-size:0; /* same trick as above */
}
.content-nav-control > span {
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  margin: 0 2px; /* BOTH MARGINS LEFT AND RIGHT */
}
.content-nav-control > span.active{
    background:blue;
}
```

**And finally:**

```
$(function () { // DOM ready shorty

    var $gal  = $('.gallery'),
        $nav  = $('.content-nav-control'),
        galSW = $gal[0].scrollWidth,       // scrollable width
        imgM  = parseInt($gal.find('img').css('marginLeft'), 10), // 20px
        galW  = $gal.width() - imgM,      // - one Margin
        n     = Math.round(galSW/galW),   // n of slides
        c     = 0,   // counter
        galIntv;     // the interval

    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        $nav.append('<span />'); // Create circles
    }
    var  $btn = $nav.find('span');
    $btn.eq(c).addClass('active');

    function anim(){
        $btn.removeClass('active').eq(c).addClass('active');
        $gal.stop().animate({scrollLeft: galW*c }, 400);
    }

    function loop(){
        galIntv =  setInterval(function(){
            c = ++c%n;
            anim();
        }, 3000);
    }
    loop(); // first start kick

    // MAKE BUTTONS CLICKABLE
    $nav.on('click', 'span', function(){
       c = $(this).index();
       anim();
    });

    // PAUSE ON GALLERY MOUSEENTER
    $gal.parent('.galleryContainer').hover(function( e ){
        return e.type=='mouseenter' ? clearInterval(galIntv) : loop() ;
    });


});
```

*"- With this solution, What can I do now and in the future? -"*
**Nothing!** just freely add images into your HTML and play, and never again have to take a look at your backyard :)

Comment: I am really impressed by your solution. Actually i am a newbie in web designing. i wish to do a lot with design, i try but fail because of lack of knowledge and experience. i wish someday i will be good in jquery. thanks a ton for your support

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/pjvCw/41/

i added new class

```
.selected
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

and modified some js code

Comment: Bro... it's not good! take a look a bit faster: http://jsfiddle.net/pjvCw/40/ The timing is getting messy

Comment: its my last attempt now, you can tune it further, we are here to give directions not spoon feed

Comment: Oh, sure, sorry It might've sound a bit rude, I had not the time to debug your code cause I was writing my example! :) now I'll take a look at what you end up with

Comment: As you can see in your example, the animations are not distributed equally due to `.delay()` and other things.  So dear Maverick I would go with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pjvCw/44/ Hope will be useful for you to get some new tricks! Happy coding and no hard feelings :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your jsfiddle edited http://jsfiddle.net/pjvCw/45/

```
var scrolled = 0;
var circles = $(".circle");
var colorCircle = function(index) {
    for(var i=0; i<circles.length; i++) {
        if(i == index) {
            circles.eq(i).css("background-color", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)");
        } else {
            circles.eq(i).css("background-color", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)");
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var A = $('.gallery').scrollLeft();
        if (A < 993) {
            $('.gallery').animate({
                scrollLeft: '+=331px'
            }, 300);
            colorCircle(++scrolled);
        }
        if (A >= 993) {
            $('.gallery').delay(400).animate({
                scrollLeft: 0
            }, 300);
            colorCircle(scrolled = 0);
        }
    }, 3000);
    colorCircle(0);
});
```

I added a transition to the .circle class, so it looks a little bit better:

```
.circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  margin-right: 5px;
  transition: background-color 700ms;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 700ms;
}
```

Comment: well... this is totally buggy :)

Comment: What you mean. Did you check the jsfiddle.

Comment: I did, when the slider comes to the beginning, the circles are supposed to turn red again, which is not happening

Comment: I thought that you need to get one circle colored at a time. And when the images slide to get another one colored. Isn't that the case.

Comment: @Krasimir no, that isn't the case

Comment: @Krasimir please look closely at **your own demo** and tell me after 6 slides what you see...

Comment: Ah ... yes you are right. I forgot to set scrolled to 0. Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/yerdW/1/

I added a line that gets the scrollLeft and divides it by your width (331px) to get the position and use that to select the 'active' circle:

```
      $(".circle").removeClass("coloured");        
       position = Math.ceil($(".gallery").scrollLeft()/331 + 2);

    if(position > $(".circle").length){
        position = 1; // yes...
    }
        $(".content-nav-control div:nth-child("+position+")").addClass("coloured");
```

Red background for active circle:

```
    .coloured {
    background : red;
    }
```

Note that you should initialise with the first circle already having the `.coloured` class applied.